# React Native - how to show a list not at the beginning of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, react-native, scroll

I need to render a list with the user rankings
Want to mount the list showing 10 positions on the screen at a time.
And always start to show the part of the list where the user is, even  if he is a the position 200 of 1000 and then the user could scroll up and down to explore the list.

Does exist a way to do it?

I'm using something like this

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { ListView } from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import ListItem from './ListItem';

    class LibraryList extends Component {
      componentWillMount() {
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        });

        this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.libraries);
      }

      renderRow(library) {
        return <ListItem library={library} />;
      }

      render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow}
            />
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return { libraries: state.libraries };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far?

Comment: Use FlatList or SectionList, ListView is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a FlatList. The ListView is deprecated and the new list is much better in terms of optimization and usability.

Now for your question, the FlatList actually has a props called [initialScrollIndex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#initialscrollindex) which allow you to decide which item you want to show at the first render

Hope it's what you're looking for!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you very much.
Now I'v to figure out how the getItemLayout works.